# How can I generate a requirements.txt file for a package not available on my development platform?

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to generate `requirements/dev.txt` and `prod.txt` files for my python project. I'm using `pip-compile-multi` to generate them from `base.in` `dev.in` and `prod.in` files. Everything works great until I add `tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0a0` into the `prod.in` file. I get this error when I do: `RuntimeError: Failed to pip-compile requirements/prod.in`.

I believe this is because tensorflow-gpu is only available on Linux, and my dev machine is a Mac. (If I run `pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0a0` I am told there is no distribution for my platform.) Is there a way I can generate a requirements.txt file for pip for a package that is not available on my platform? To be clear, my goal is to generate a `requirements.txt` file using something like `pip-compile-multi` (because that will version dependencies) that will only install on Linux, but I want to be able to actually *generate* the file on any platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently pip-tools doesn't support this, there's [an open issue on github](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools/issues/585). A [workaround](https://github.com/peterdemin/pip-compile-multi/issues/145#issuecomment-497462700) suggested by the author of pip-compile-multi is to generate a `linux.txt` on a linux machine, and then statically link that to a non-generated `linux-prod.txt` like this

```
-r prod.txt
-r linux.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Use environment markers from [PEP 496](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0496/):

```
tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0a0; sys_platform!='darwin'
```

Comment: This gets me to a non-breaking point, but it doesn't actually include tensorflow-gpu in the generated requirements.txt. What I want to be able to do is generate a requirements.txt file for Linux, using a tool like `pip-compile` ran on my Mac. Unless that's a misguided goal...

Answer (score 1):

You could run `pip-compile-multi` in a Docker container. That way you'd be running it under Linux, and you could do that on your Mac or other dev machines. As a one-liner, it might look something like this:

`docker run --rm --mount type=bind,src=$(pwd),dst=/code -w /code python:3.8 bash -c "pip install pip-compile-multi && pip-compile-multi"`

I haven't used `pip-compile-multi`, so I'm not exactly sure how you call it. Maybe you'd need to add some arguments to that command. Depending on how complicated your setup is, you could consider writing a `Dockerfile` and simplifying the one-liner a bit.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for `tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0a0` (remove the `-` before the `a`). I think this is the version you are looking for: https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-gpu/2.0.0a0/
See the pip install command on the page. Hope this helps.

Comment: The question is how to generate `requirements.txt` that works on MacOS where the package is not available.

Comment: I think the mac version is ` pip install tensorflow==2.0.0a0` The reason I say this is because macbooks are not CUDA enabled as described here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/93354/is-my-mac-book-pro-suitable-for-cuda

Comment: The question is how to include `tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0a0` into `requirements.txt` so that `requrements.txt` works on MacOS.